Sampling from tail of Normal distribution
In this 1963 paper by Marsaglia the following method of sampling from the tail of the Normal distribution is described. Can someone help me see the math of why the density of U1 conditioned on (1) is what is stated in the last paragraph and why the density of X is a multiple of the standard normal density. Thank you. 

For "the density of $X$ is a multiple of the standard normal density", this is what you would expect in general for a truncated density.   If the distribution of the underlying  random variable $Y$ has density $f_Y(y)$ then the distribution truncated to support $S$ has density $f_{Y \mid Y \in S}(y)= \frac{1}{\mathbb P(Y \in S)}f_Y(y) \mathbf I_{[y \in S]}$.

The core idea$^1$ is to simulate an Exponential $\mathcal {Exp}(1/2)$ variate $Y$, translated by $a^2$ and then take its square root
$$X=(a^2+Y)^{1/2}=(a^2-2\log U)^{1/2}$$
This can be seen as a proposal in an accept-reject algorithm, with the bound on $U_2$ being the acceptance bound. Alternatively, the distribution of the accepted $X$'s can directly derived as follows.
Since $(U_1,U_2)$ has density $$\mathbb I_{[0,1]^2}(u_1,u_2)$$
the probability that $$U_2<a(a^2-2\log U_1)^{-1/2}\tag{1}$$ conditional on $U_1$, is
$$a(a^2-2\log U_1)^{-1/2}$$
Therefore the density of $U_1$ constrained by (1) is
$$p(u_1)\propto \underbrace{\mathbb I_{[0,1]}(u_1)}_\text{(i)}\underbrace{(a^2-2\log u_1)^{-1/2}}_\text{(ii)}$$
as the product of (i) the marginal density of $U_1$ and (ii) the probability of selecting that $U_1$ based on (1).
Since $X=(a^2-2\log U_1)^{1/2}$ is a bijective transform of $U_1$, taking values over $(a,\infty)$, with
$$U_1=\exp\{-(X^2-a^2)/2\}$$
the density of $X$ is
\begin{align}
q(x)
&\propto p(U_1(x)) \times \left|\frac{\text dU_1(x)}{\text dx}\right|\\
&=\mathbb I_{[0,1]}(U_1(x))(a^2-2\log U_1(x))^{-1/2}\times x\exp\{-(x^2-a^2)/2\}\\
&= I_{[a,\infty)}(x) \frac{1}{x} \times x\exp\{-(x^2-a^2)/2\}\\
&= I_{[a,\infty)}(x) \exp\{-(x^2-a^2)/2\}\\
&\propto I_{[a,\infty)}(x) \exp\{-x^2/2\}
\end{align}

¹In my [more recent] paper, I use instead an Exponential $\mathcal {Exp}(\alpha)$ variate, translated by $a$ (and optimised in $\alpha$).
